# Can't get express routing parameter to work

Tags: api, express

I'm working on this express API but when I pass a parameter to test in postman I keep getting this error "Cannot GET /api/v1/profile/psn/sharad0987"

The code is below:

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

const app = express()

//load Env 
dotenv.config({path: './config.env'})

app.get('api/v1/profile/:platform/:gamertag', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.platform, req.params.gamertag);
    res.send('Hello')
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.listen(port,
   console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${port}`)
)
```

Please what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing leading slash. Looking at [routing documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) that should work as soon as it is added. Could you try:

```
app.get('/api/v1/profile/:platform/:gamertag', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.platform, req.params.gamertag);
    res.send('Hello');
});
```

If that is not working, can you update your question with actual postman data you are trying to use